# Contar registros de tablas relacionadas agrupados por campo de tabla pivot

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

Os solicito ayuda para realizar la siguiente consulta. Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas (courses, course_user, users) con los siguientes campos:

1. Tabla **courses**: id, denomination, hours.
2. Tabla **course_user**: id, course_id, user_id, inscription_type (este campo puede tener dos valores posibles TITULAR o RESERVA.
3. Tabla **users**: id, nif, name, surname.

En los modelos tengo creadas las funciones de relación correspondientes:

Modelo **Course**:

```
public function courseUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('inscription_type')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Modelo **User**:

```
public function userCourses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withPivot('inscription_type')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Lo que necesito obtener es la relación de todos los cursos existentes con el total de matriculas por curso, añadiendo además dos campos contadores donde se el desglose del total de matriculas obtenida por curso indicando cuantas de esas matriculas tienen en el campo **inscription_type** el valor **TITULAR** y otro que indique cuanta tienen el valor **RESERVA**.

El resultado debería ser algo así:

| Id | Curso | Horas | Nº Matriculas | Nº Titulares | Nº Reservas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Excel | 20 | 150 | 125 | 25 |

Tengo creado el siguiente join:

```
$courses = DB::table('courses') ->leftJoin('course_user', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_user.course_id') ->select('courses.*', DB::raw('count(*) as TotalMatriculas')) ->groupBy('courses.id') ->get();
```

Con esto saco todos los cursos con el total de matrículas que tiene cada uno, pero no sé como obtener ahora el conteo de las matrículas que son de tipo TITULAR y las que son de tipo RESERVA.

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola compañeros, nadie que pueda ayudarme con este tema?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? La solución es agrupar por `id` del curso, contar todas y además por `inscription_type`

Comment: Hola Marcos. Tengo creado el siguiente join:

$courses = DB::table('courses')
   ->leftJoin('course_user', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_user.course_id')
   ->select('courses.*', DB::raw('count(*) as TotalMatriculas'))
   ->groupBy('courses.id')
   ->get();

Con saco todos los cursos con el total de matriculas que tiene cada uno, pero no sé como obtener ahora el conteo de las matriculas que son de tipo TITULAR y las que son de tipo RESERVA.

Te agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar `IF()` y `SUM()` así:

```
SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "TITULAR", 1, 0)) AS TotalTitulares,
SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "RESERVA", 1, 0)) AS TotalReservas,
```

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$courses = DB::table('courses') 
    ->leftJoin('course_user', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_user.course_id') 
    ->select('courses.*', DB::raw('count(*) as TotalMatriculas'), DB::raw('SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "TITULAR", 1, 0)) AS TotalTitulares'), DB::raw('SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "RESERVA", 1, 0)) AS TotalReservas')) 
     ->groupBy('courses.id') ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos, por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Me surge el siguiente inconveniente. La consulta funciona perfectamente en local pero al subirlo al HOST me lanza un ERROR 500 SERVER ERROR. Al consultar el log me indica "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'u934279908_dbsgiccooand.courses.denomination' isn't in GROUP BY....".
He comprobado y las bases de datos son semejantes pero no sé porque en local funciona de forma correcta y en el host lanza ese error. ¿Alguna idea?. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. El error es porque hay que añadir todos los campos del select en el groupBy. Finalmente la consulta queda asi:

$courses = DB::table('courses') 
->leftJoin('course_user', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_user.course_id') 
->select('courses.*', DB::raw('SUM(IF(course_user.course_id > 0, 1 ,0)) AS TotalMatriculas'), DB::raw('SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "TITULAR", 1, 0)) AS TotalTitulares'), DB::raw('SUM(IF(course_user.inscription_type = "RESERVA", 1, 0)) AS TotalReservas')) 
->groupBy('courses.id', 'courses.denomination', 'courses.hours', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
->get();